# How to channel output of one process as input to the next process in Nextflow?

Tags: nextflow

Can any Nextflow user please demonstrate how to channel output from one process as input to the next process?

My script is

```
//process 6
process blastn {


    input:
    tuple val(query_id), path(query)
    path db

    output:
    tuple val(query_id), path ("${query.baseName}_blast_sort.tsv"), emit: blastHits

    script:
    """
    blastn \
        -query ${query} -db "${db}/${db_name}/nt" \
        -outfmt 11 -out ${query.baseName}_blast.asn \
        -evalue ${params.evalue} \
        -num_threads ${task.cpus}

    
    blast_formatter \
        -archive ${query.baseName}_blast.asn \
        -outfmt "6 qaccver saccver pident length evalue bitscore stitle" -out ${query.baseName}_blast_unsort.tsv
                
    """
}

//process 7
process topBlastHits {
    
    input:
    path(x)

    output:
    path ("*.tsv") 

    script:
    """
    cat $x | awk 'FNR>=1 && FNR<=5' > ${x.simpleName}.TopBlastHitsWithHeader.tsv
        
    """
}
```

Workflow definition

```
blastn (renameContigFastaHeader.out.contig_seq, db_path)


topBlastHits(blastn.out.blastHits) 
        | collectFile(name: 'TopBlastHitsWithHeader.tsv', keepHeader: true, skip: 1, storeDir: "$PWD/results") 
        | view
```

The process "topBlastHits" gets terminated with an error "Not a valid path value:'sample1'

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

I also tried the following workflow without any success

```
topBlastHits(blastn.out) 
        | collectFile(name: 'TopBlastHitsWithHeader.tsv', keepHeader: true, skip: 1, storeDir: "$PWD/results") 
        | view
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed a couple things.

1. I'm a little confused what you're trying to achieve with the `collectFile` operator. The `publishDir` [directive](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#publishDir) is how you usually publish results from work directories.
2. The error you're getting also seems confusing. I would expect an error about input cardinality (i.e., `Input tuple does not match input set cardinality declared by process 'topBlastHits'`). Your input declaration doesn't match a tuple. Changing it to the following may resolve your issues.

```
//process 7
process topBlastHits {
    tag "query_id"    

    publishDir(
      path: params.outDir,
      mode: 'copy',
    )

    input:
    tuple val(query_id), path(blast_res)

    output:
    path ("*.tsv")

    script:
    """
    cat $blast_res | awk 'FNR>=1 && FNR<=5' > ${query_id}.TopBlastHitsWithHeader.tsv
    """
}
```